# A value is missing in my iterator and I don't know why

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator, yield

I've got a very basic generator where you can send during the loop a new value through the yield callback:

```
def GenInter(x, y):

    while (x+1 < y):
        callback = (yield x)
        if callback is not None:
            x = callback
        else:
            x += 1
```

Then, I create a generator:

```
myGen = GenInter(10,25)
```

And finally, I'm parsing it with a for loop. When it's "15", I want to go directly to "20".

```
for x in myGen:
    if x == 15:
        myGen.send(20)
    print(x)
```

Here is the result:

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
21
22
23
```

How come the "20" value is missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: when in 15 you are advancing the iterator one, but in the next for iteration it is advanced again, that is why you are missing it

Comment: The `myGen.send(20)` will yield that `20`, which you ignore. The next time through the loop, you get the `21`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `send` call actually runs an iteration and returns a value and you aren't doing anything with it.

Try this:

```
print(myGen.send(20))
```

https://repl.it/repls/RuddyConcretePrinters

Comment: Note that this will print `20` *before* `15`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the iteration and the result were returned by the send itself. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Imreal and by @Abarnert, `myGen.send(20)` yields the missing 20. You can resolve your issue by changing your iteration to this:

```
for x in myGen:
    y = x
    if x == 15:
        y = myGen.send(20)
    print(y)
```

It returns the following output:

```
10
11
12
13
14
20
21
22
23
```